# Rails 3 + Devise : issue with custom routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, authentication, devise, rails-routing

I've followed the Devise [wiki](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Change-the-default-sign_in-and-sign_out-routes) to switch the login route from `/users/sign_in` to `/login`. My routes file looks like this:

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => { :omniauth_callbacks => "users/omniauth_callbacks" }

devise_scope :user do
  get '/login'    , :to => 'devise/sessions#new'    , :as => :login
  delete '/logout', :to => 'devise/sessions#destroy', :as => :logout
end
```

and my user model has this

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :omniauthable, :database_authenticatable
end
```

I have a common scenario where a user is logged out, tries to access a restricted page, and then redirected to log himself in.

However, when that user is redirected, devise sends them to `/users/sign_in` path instead of `/login`.

The only way I could make the redirection to the `/login` url work is by adding this to the top of my `routes.rb`:

```
match "/users/sign_in" => redirect('/login')
```

which adds a redirect to my application, which in turn messes up tests - whenever I do something like this:

```
current_url.should == login_path
```

I get an error saying the expected path was "/login" and the actual was "/users/sign_in".

Did I miss something here - what's an elegant way to work around it? thanks.

#### side note

I only use `:omniauthable` to authenticate, but I added `:database_authenticatable` to devise configuration to force it to go to a dedicated login page.

Otherwise,  devise always directs to the root path, so it would seem. If you know of a better way to do that, please - chime in.

Comment: Always check the project's wiki pages: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Change-the-default-sign_in-and-sign_out-routes

Comment: I did - see the first sentence :)

Comment: Then why aren't you overriding the url helpers like in the wiki page? `:as => :new_user_session`